# Android FirebaseAuth not working in Android API Level 26

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm experiencing authentication problems for an app targeting *API Level 26*, where I use the `FirebaseAuth#signInWithEmailAndPassword` method to log into a Firebase database: the same code, i.e.

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword("a@b.com","pwd");`

works correctly until API Level 24, whereas it doesn't with the latest API Level26.

When I say *It works*, I mean that an `AuthStateListener` added to the `FirebaseAuth` with

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);`

fires `onAuthStateChanged` correctly after signin in with a current user as expected until API Level 24, wherease it does not fire if I test the app with API Level 26 (in this case the event fires only once after adding the `AuthStateListener` and `FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()` gives me back a `null` as the current user. Afterwards It fires no more, even if I call `FirebaseAuth#signInWithEmailAndPassword` as mentioned above).

The Firebase libraries I'm using are version 11.4.2, as set in the gradle script dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance, regards

Comment: Check your logcat for `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`. Your device/emulator may have on old version of Google Play services that does not support API level 26.

Comment: @BobSnyder 's solution is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder and sorry for being late back to you. At first I tried updating Play Services but without success. Today I got back to that project, started the emulator, confirmed some permissions that Play Services asked for and now it works.